# Java - Can we reduce execution time of this program?

Tags: java, arrays, time, execution-time

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/immediate-smaller-element1142/1

**Problem - if next immediate number is smaller then modify array element to that else -1.
This works in 0.51 sec on C/C++ but on java its taking more then 5.55 sec, which is not allowed by the problem's condition. Please help someone.**

```
class Solution {
void immediateSmaller(int arr[], int n) {
    // code here
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]) arr[i]=arr[i+1];
        else arr[i]=-1;
    }
    arr[n-1]=-1;
}}
```

Error-
Runtime Error:

Runtime ErrorTime Limit Exceeded

Your program took more time than expected.Time Limit Exceeded

Expected Time Limit 5.55sec

Hint : Please optimize your code and submit again.

Comment: There's nothing you can do to improve _this_ code: it's as good as it can get.  However, the driver code provided by GCD for this particular challenge sucks.   Every successful Java submitter for this problem seems to have somehow managed to replace the provided driver with something better.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that for(..) - nice and tight.  Should be O(N) as indicated.   If this program is 5+ seconds, something else is going on.   Show the "// code here"

Comment: Thanks @KevinAnderson, I also thought the same, so for the java the problem should increase the time limit, right?